# On the INSERT statement in H2, what does `DIRECT` mean?

Tags: insert, h2

I noticed on the grammar documentation for [`INSERT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#insert) in the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), the optional word `DIRECT`. The documentation says:

> When using DIRECT, then the results from the query are directly applied in the target table without any intermediate step.

When is data inserted *not* “directly applied”? What are these “intermediated steps”?

➥ What is the purpose of `DIRECT`?

➥ In what scenarios might one be motivated to use this feature?